# Setting snapping unit to map units using QGIS

Tags: qgis, snapping

I'm going through the QGIS training Manual and I got stuck trying to set up the snapping unit to map units at the Forestry Application 14.3 Digitizing Forest Stands.
The manual indicates to set the snapping units in Map units but the only available options are meters and pixels.

I am using QGIS 3.22.1.

Comment: Which CRS are you working with?

Comment: As indicated by the manual 3067

Comment: https://epsg.io/3067 - UoM is `m`.

Comment: In my experience it is easier to use a radius of 10-12 pixels. This works with layers in projected coordinate systems (UTM for example) or latitude longitude ones (like EPSG 4326)

Comment: The CRS indicated at the Manual 3067

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like statements of appreciation within your posts.

Comment: My guess is that like with many other issues, the QGIS training manual has not been updated to version 3.22 and the snapping units do no offer the "map units" option any longer but directly the project 's actual unit of measurement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This setting is dependent on the map unit of the **project** CRS, not of the layer CRS.

Here the project is in 3857, map unit is meter

[image]

and now the project CRS is in 4326, map unit is degree

[image]